# Issue with dirty form jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble using two plugins. I have tried:

https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

In my code I am using:

```
<script>
    $(funtion() {
        $('form').dirtyForms();
    });
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
    $(funtion() {
        $('form').areYouSure();
    });
</script>
```

within my header and when I change elements of the form and try to refresh I get no dialouge. I am struggling to work out how I can tell if it's being called at all.

I can't for the life of me get it to work. Any ideas?

Below is a view source example of a page with it in:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css?v=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/content.css?v=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/footer.css?v=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.datetimepicker.css?v=1.0">

        <script src="scripts/jquery191.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/mdetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            if(MobileEsp.DetectTierIphone() == true) {
                var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
                metaTag.name = "viewport"
                metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1"
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
            }

            if(MobileEsp.DetectTierTablet() == true) {
                var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
                metaTag.name = "viewport"
                metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1"
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
            }

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/widget-print.js"></script> 

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTHOXfueJyei11NqPw3rRjhjj_yjcdV-E&callback=initMap"></script>

        <script src="scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            <!--
            function HideContent(d) {
                document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
            }
            function ShowContent(d) {
                document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
            }
            function ReverseDisplay(d) {
                if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
                else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
            }
            //-->
        </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("BodyshopAddress").each(function(){                         
                var embed ="<iframe width='200' height='200' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' style='margin-left:30px;'  src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) +"&amp;output=embed&iwloc'></iframe>";
                $(this).html(embed);
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script>
            $(funtion() {
                 $('form').dirtyForms();
            });
        </script>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>      

    <div class="container">
            <div class="MainHeader">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="logged_container">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="navigation_container">          
                ...
            </div>

        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-right:10px; margin-top:5px; background-color:#4771A5; border-radius:3px; padding:5px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 25px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.7);">
            <form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
                <input type='text' size='20' name='Poke' placeholder='Magic Poking Stick' style="margin-right:5px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">&nbsp;<input type='submit' name='BadBoyPoke' value='' class='submit' title='Search' maxlength="3" style='background-image:url(&quot;img/bms121.png&quot;); vertical-align:middle;' >  
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() 
                { 
                    $('#RepairerNetworkTable').tablesorter({
                        widthFixed : true,
                        headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
                        widgets: [ 'stickyHeaders', 'filter', 'print' ],
                        widgetOptions: {
                            stickyHeaders_attachTo : '.wrapper',

                            print_title      : '',          // this option > caption > table id > "table"
                            print_dataAttrib : 'data-name', // header attrib containing modified header name
                            print_rows       : 'f',         // (a)ll, (v)isible or (f)iltered
                            print_columns    : 's',         // (a)ll, (v)isible or (s)elected (columnSelector widget)
                            print_extraCSS   : '',          // add any extra css definitions for the popup window here
                            print_styleSheet : 'styles/tablePrint.css', // add the url of your print stylesheet
                            print_callback   : function(config, $table, printStyle){
                                $.tablesorter.printTable.printOutput( config, $table.html(), printStyle );
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $('.print').click(function(){
                        $('.tablesorter').trigger('printTable');
                    });
                } 
            );
        </script>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentTableView">
                            <a href="#" class="print" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">
                            <img src="img/bms91.png" alt="" height="16" style="vertical-align:top; padding-right:5px;">Print</a>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="GridViewContainer wrapper">
                                <table  id="RepairerNetworkTable" class="tablesorter">                          
                                    ...
                                </table> 
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="TabbedViewContainer">
                            <div class="TabbedNavContainer">
                                <div style="position: relative;  top: 50%;  transform: translateY(-50%);">
                                    <form action="" method="post">
                                        <a style="text-decoration:underline !important;" href="repairer_network.php?RepNetID=9&RepNetTab=Info">Info</a>

                                        <a href="repairer_network.php?RepNetID=9&RepNetTab=WorkProviders">Work Providers / Brokers</a>

                                        <a href="repairer_network.php?RepNetID=9&RepNetTab=Bodyshops">Bodyshops</a>

                                        <input name="submitInfo" type="submit" value="Change Repairer Network's Info" />

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">
                                <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;">Repairer Network Info: </span>
                                <br />
                                <hr size='1' style=" margin: 5px 10px 5px 0; ">
                                <table style="float:left;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Name: </td>
                                        <td><input name="BusinessName" type="text" size="30" value="AI Claims Solutions (UK) Ltd"/> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Email: </td>
                                        <td><input name="BusinessEmail" type="text" size="30" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Phone: </td>
                                        <td><input name="BusinessPhone" type="text" size="30" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                    </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />              
                    </div>  
        <div class="footer">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's simple to use. Just add the following line to your page's ready function:
>   $('form').areYouSure(); [Are You Sure? - A light "dirty forms" JQuery Plugin](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').areYouSure();
});
```

That's what the plugin says... it listen to the element $('form') (you could use an id or class) and when the "event" "areYouSure()" occurs, the plugin will trigger...

Comment: That isn't the issue. The problem is that the jquery selector is not attaching to the form tag. I am creating a different question as this isn't very clear.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you correctly. I think it uses a listener on the [onunload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) and check the stae of the form elements, so probably you coul emulate it's functionality by calling a function that check the content of form on that event...

Comment: Turns out I had to use the class selector instead of trying to use a tag selector. +1 for trying anyway. It was helpful.